# Can I use the 2to3 package or something similar from the python code itself to check if code works in Python 3 and upgrade it if not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2to3

I want to be able to check if a function is compatible with Python 3 from the python code (not through a terminal). A string containing the function would be passed into the check.

As far as I know I can only use 2to3 in the terminal to convert Python documents from Python 2 to Python 3. Is there a way I can use this or something else to first check the code in a string and, if it needs to be converted to Python 3, to write the necessary changes back to the string?

How I would like it to work:

```
def checkCodeCompatibility(functionInString):
    if codeIncompatibleWithPython3:
         return convertCodeToPython3(functionInString)
```

Comment: Given that both cases result in code that is compatible with Python 3, what's the reason for checking and not just running the compatibility tool regardless?

Comment: *As far as I know I can only use 2to3 in the terminal:* not true. Look at the code and you will see what classes to use from a program.

Comment: @Kemp Running the compatibility tool on code that is already compatible can cause incorrect changes in some cases, so it's preferable to not have to run the tool unnecessarily.